# How to stop batch file from echoing extra line into file?

Tags: file, batch-file, echo

I have the following code to read how long a variable is by echoing it into a file, than reading the file length:

```
echo %scor% > scorfile.txt
FOR %%? IN (scorfile.txt) DO ( SET /A scorlength=%%~z? - 2 )
if %scorlength%==12 set /a scorlength=1
del /Q scorfile.txt
echo %scorlength%
pause
```

It believes the variable is an extra character long, and when I open scorfile.txt, there is an extra line, and I believe this is what is causing the problem. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @WeeTomatoBall, `echo %scor% > scorfile.txt` is `echo`ing `%scor%[space]` to the file. That space is obviously an extra character! Use either `>scorfile.txt echo %scor%`, or preferably `(echo %scor%) 1>"scorfile.txt"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
echo | set /p="%scor%" > scorfile.txt
FOR %%? IN (scorfile.txt) DO ( SET /A scorlength=%%~z? )
if %scorlength%==12 set /a scorlength=1
del /Q scorfile.txt
echo %scorlength%
pause
```

The first and second lines are modified. The first modification removes the newline from the output, and the second modification strips the `- 2` part of the equation you had, since I assumed you were originally using it in hopes of trying to compensate for the newline character count issue.

Hope this solves your problem!